# Two independent Poisson process question

Tags: poisson-distribution

If I have two independent Poisson processes, X and Y, with X having a lambda 2 and Y having a lambda 3. Given that the starting value for Y is 3 and X is zero, then how do I calculate the probability of X being larger than Y at any given point, even if only for one instant in time.
I realize that I can just simulate my way out of it, but that does not really seem like an elegant solution. Any help/directions would be much appreciated.

Besides the solution below, is it possible to use the CDF and pmf of a Poisson distribution instead of only its PMF, see below.

$1-\prod_{t=1}^{\infty}\bigg[\prod_{k=0}^{\infty} \bigg [1-\bigg(1-e^{-\lambda_1*t}\cdot \sum_{i=0}^{k+D+1}\bigg[\frac{(\lambda_1*t)^{i}}{i!}\bigg]\bigg)\cdot \frac{(\lambda_2*t)^{k}*e^{-\lambda_2*t}}{k!}\bigg]\bigg]
$

My idea was that we find the probability that Poisson distribution X with Lambda 2 receives k+3+1 more occurrences conditioned on the fact that Poisson distribution Y gets equal to k occurrences. This is done for all k and then subsequently we do it for all points in time. Is this also a correct way of doing it?

Comment: You really *should* run a simulation, if only to check any analytical answers.  I might be misunderstanding your question, but my simulations produce values around $0.40$.

Comment: Hmm probably true, currently I get values around 0.30 with analytical, this is the probability that process X exceeds process Y at any given point.

Comment: @Whuber would you mind sharing your simulation code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick some time point $t > 0$. We know that $X(t) \sim \text{Poisson}(2t)$ and $Y(t) - 3 \sim \text{Poisson}(3t)$. You are asking for $P(X(t) > Y(t))$. Independence comes in handy.

\begin{align}
P(X(t) > Y(t)) &= \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} P[X(t) = k+j \cap Y(t) = k ] \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} P[X(t) = k+j] P[ Y(t) = k ] \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=3}^{\infty} P[X(t) = k+j] P[ Y(t) = k ] \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k'=0}^{\infty} P[X(t) = k'+3+j] P[ Y(t) - 3 = k' ] \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k'=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-2t}(2t)^{k'+3+j}}{(k'+3+j)!} \frac{e^{-3t}(3t)^{k'}}{k'!} \\
\end{align}

Edit: this might actually be simpler...

\begin{align*}
1-P(X(t)\le Y(t)) &= 1 - \sum_{i=0}^j\sum_{j=3}^{\infty}P(X(t)=j-i)P(Y(t)=j) \\
&= 1-\sum_{j=3}^{\infty} P(X(t)\le j)P(Y(t)=j) \\
&= 1-\sum_{j'=0}^{\infty} P(X(t)\le j'+3)P(Y(t)-3=j') 
\end{align*}

Which you can approximate in R by typing

```
calcProb <- function(t)
{
  sumVal <- 0
  for(jprime in 0:1000){
    sumVal <- sumVal + ppois(jprime+3, 2*t)*dpois(jprime,3*t)
  }
  return(1-sumVal)
}

#plot
t <- seq(0,50,.1)
probs <- sapply(t, calcProb)
plot(t,probs, type="l")
```

And you can see how this probability changes as $t$ changes. This makes sense to me because $Y(t)$ starts higher and grows faster than $X(t)$.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the help!
I have a code snippet from R that I created before I saw your solution, we get almost the same result but not quite:

for (j in 1:100){
  for (i in 0:100){
    
    val=val*(1-(1-ppois(i+3,2*j))*ppois(0+i,3*j))
    print(1-val)  
    }  
}  

As far as I can see we are doing pretty much the same thing right? But the results differ a bit.

Comment: @nonein see my edit

Comment: Awesome! This is somewhat what I ended up doing, I do have one question though when using ppois wouldn't it be 1-ppois? As we are interested in calculating the probability of exceeding?

Lastly, how come we are adding the probabilities and not multiplying them?

Comment: @nonein last question: because $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B)$ if $A \cap B = \emptyset$. First question,  no, the code inside the for loop estimates the value of the sum of the last line, which has cdfs of X and pmfs of Y-3

Comment: Sorry for not understanding completely.

 Normally when wanting to the probability of event A happening conditional on event B isn't that then P(A)*P(B)? Just like we do with the pmf and CDF.

Regarind the R-code I am unsure what you mean, in the code above we multiply the probability of scoring jprime +3 or below multiplied by the probability of scoring jprime. Aren't we interested in the probability of scoring above jprime multiplied by the probability of scoring exactly jprime in poisson process Y?

Comment: You would be extremely well advised to continue your plot beyond the value of $t=10$.  Plot it to $t=50$ and see what happens.

Comment: great catch @whuber. I increased the number of iterations to 1000 so the probability doesn't go to 1 as $t \to \infty$. Definitely a mistake. It should be good now. I'll attach the picture later. For some CV doesn't like my image files right now

Comment: @nonein " Normally when wanting to the probability of event A happening conditional on event B isn't that then P(A)*P(B)? " no, definitely not. Regarding your other question, it'll be easier for me to answer if you ask me about a specific step I did

Comment: Okay, so the way I thought about the problem and structured my solution is as follows: I want the probability that either X>3 and Y=0, or X>4 and Y=1 and so forth. Thus I take the individual probability of each of these events not happening, and multiply them. 1 is subtracted from the result to arrive at the total probability at a given time t. How come you are adding the probabilities of the individual events happening? I am sorry if this seems a little confused. We ALMOST get the same results, and if there is a large difference between process X and Y the result basically the same.

Comment: I"m afraid I don't understand how this answers the question, which appears to be about whether $X(t)$ can exceed $Y(t)$ *at any (unspecified) time $t$*.  It looks like your analysis tries to answer the question for some *specific time* $t$ only.  (That answer is provided by a Skellam distribution.)

Comment: First I calculate it for any specific time and then generalized it for t approaching infinity.

I.e. P(X(t)>3+Y(t)) for all t's. I.e. $1-\prod_{t=1}^{\infty}(1-P(X(t)>3+Y(t)))$

Comment: @whuber These are one and the same. Just checked. Never heard of a Skellam distribution. Pretty cool.

Comment: @nonein $P(X(t) > Y(t)) \neq P(X(t) > 3 +Y(t))$

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/skellam/index.html <- awesome

Comment: @Taylor Yeah I agree but what we are trying to estimate is the probability that X at any given time is not only above Y but also above its starting point, hence 3+Y(t). Unless I am misunderstanding something

Comment: @Taylor I have an additional question if you don't mind, how do I aggregate the total probability that X exceeds Y at any given time, i.e. for all t's. Is it correct to do as I have done in my edit in my post?